# Eclipse how to add new webservice runtime in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services

I like to add new webservice runtime environment in eclipse (kepler,luna ..)

Currently by default there are three options Axis, Axis2,Apache CFX.

but i want to use either metro /weblogic etc.

Is there any option i can do this in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Search for plugins in eclipse which can help you. For metro , I found one here

```
https://metro.java.net/2.1/guide/Developing_with_Eclipse.html
```

Comment: Am looking for client generation from eclipse not from command line.i.e eclipse has inbuild webserivce runtime configuration for Axis etc i want to know whether i can add other webservice runtime like metro in eclipse